# Смешивание изображений . Скетч эффект

Tags: android, изображения

Подскажите как применить следующие эффекты к изображению в android? Какие функции и библиотеки использовать чтобы достичь результата?

Сперва выбираю картинку

[image]

Затем выбираю изображение с которым хочу смешать

[image]

И в результате должно получиться что-то наподобие

[image]

Подскажите если есть какие-то идеи как это реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы смешать 2 изображения я использовал класс PorterDuffXfermode из модуля android.graphics, который содержит в себе правила смешивания bitmap'ов различными способами. 
Например

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawingBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode (android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN)); // способ смешивания
    canvas.drawBitmap(destinationBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант - руками. Первую картинку переводишь в оттенки серого. Вторую картинку используешь как маску по принципу:

dst = srs*(1.-msk/255)+msk;

Это общая идея, конкретную формулу надо подобрать, сейчас не могу заниматься этим). А так, копай в эту сторону.